# HTML5 ServiceWorker slows down page loading dramatically

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, service-worker

I am using Google Lighthouse to figure out ways to speed up my page loading time.

One of the red points was that I was missing a Service Worker.
So I get one working.

Before I used the Service Worker my page was fully loaded and ready in 7 seconds.
After I added the Service Worker my page fully loads in 29 seconds!

When I check on Fiddler was is going on, it looks like the Service Worker is loading all the files before letting the page render.

I am using the SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin plugin in my webpack.config to automatically generate the service-worker.js file because my libraries name are hashed automatically to optimize the caching.

This is my webpack.config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackChunkHash = require('webpack-chunk-hash');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
var SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');

// To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
require('babel-polyfill');

require('file-loader');
require('css-loader');
require('style-loader');
require('html-webpack-template');

/* Shared Dev & Production */

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  entry: {
    index: [
        // To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
        'babel-polyfill',
        './index.js'
    ],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-redux', 'history', 'react-router-dom', 'redux', 'react-router-redux', 'redux-form', 'lodash'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /\/favicon.ico$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              name: '[path][name][hash].[ext]',
              publicPath: '/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/style'),
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.xml/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
  },

  plugins: [
    // New moment.js optimization
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      appMountId: 'app-root',
      inlineManifestWebpackName: 'webpackManifest',
      template: 'templateIndex.html',
      title: 'Our Site',
    }),

    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin()
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};

//if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
config.plugins = [
  ...config.plugins,
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}),
];
//}

//if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
config.output.filename = '[name].[chunkhash].js';
config.plugins = [
  ...config.plugins,
  new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
  new WebpackChunkHash(),
  /*new ChunkManifestPlugin({
    filename: 'chunk-manifest.json',
    manifestVariable: 'webpackManifest',
    inlineManifest: true,
  }),*/
];
//}

module.exports = config;
```

And my templateIndex.html (I am using HtmlWebpackPlugin for the same reason, hashed files name)
The service loader is loaded at the end of the body.
If I remove it, things are fast again. But then Lighthouse complains...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#242424" />

  <title itemprop="name">My Site</title>

  <base href="/">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/images/favicon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/images/favicon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/favicon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/images/favicon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/images/favicon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/images/favicon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/images/favicon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/images/favicon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/images/favicon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">

  <link type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // ServiceWorker is a progressive technology. Ignore unsupported browsers
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
      }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('CLIENT: service worker is not supported.');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have searched on Google and I could not find anything related to the issue I am experiencing.
Is that the expected behavior? Because if that is so, then I will not use a Service Loader.
Otherwise, does anyone have a clue about how to get my page to load in parallel to the Service Worker?

Answer (score 2):

You should most likely register the SW *after* the load event of the page. Currently you're registering the SW right away when the browser executes the script in the HTML script tag. The registration is even happening before any critical app logic since Webpack most likely inserts your actual JS files just before the closing body tag.

More on the topic over here with good details and explanations!
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration